# Jersey-test with 2 servlets REST and static html

Tags: java, rest, testing, jersey

I'm using JerseyTest to test a RESTFull API with success. My problem resides in the fact that I also need to provide static html files.
I searched how to do it with the WebAppDescriptor.Builder without success.

If I would define this in a web.xml file I would have 2 different servlets: one for RESTFULL services and another for static html files.

Does anyone knows how to do this with jerseyTest? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you simply trying to publish static web files inside your web app? What does jerseyTest have to do with it? jersey test is simply for testing rest services are you trying to use it to retrieve static web files?

Comment: If you want to serve static files and are using maven simply put them in the src/main/webapp directory. This will put them at the root of your web application. Make sure your <servlet-mapping> is not using the /* for your rest application though. You would need to change it to a sub path like /rest/* or /rest/v1/* if you version your rest api.

Comment: Maybe I failed to explain myself correctly. I have a restfull web application that I want to test. I'm using selenium for that. The web part of the web application is 100% javascript so I have to serve the initial html file, some javascript files and some images. I also want to do this with an embeded server like jersey-test provides, but maybe the jersey test is not the best option.. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I typically use the maven jetty plugin for unit testing all my web services. Maven has an integration testing plugin that I use to start jetty before running all my unit tests and stop it at the end of all unit tests. I can use jetty to test my jax-ws, rest and gwt rpc services. For jersey testing I use jersey-client to test my request response's. This was the most flexible option that I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I'm using grizzly and following the tutorial on this page: https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_aplication_sharing_grizzly_with

This is exactly what I need.

Thank you all.